# Document ready's .on() function not picking up events triggered by 'onload' function

Tags: focus, blur, onblur

Why won't this work?
I have a series of events where 
`<body onload="">` ===triggers==> my `autoload()` function ===should trigger===> `$(document).ready` ===should trigger==> `console.log(' FOCUS/BLUR EVENT ');`

Now my `autoLoad()` function below is clearly triggered, since it turns the inputs' background-colors to red, however no "FOCUS EVENT" or "BLUR EVENT" messages are logged in the console.  With 4 `<inputs>` tags, I would think that I'd get 4 "FOCUS EVENT" & 4 "BLUR EVENT" messages.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>        
    <script>
        function consoleLogger1() { 
            console.log(' FOCUS EVENT ');
        }
        function consoleLogger2() { 
            console.log(' BLUR EVENT ');
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){                   //EVENT LISTENER
            $("form input").on("focus", consoleLogger1); 
            $("form input").on("blur", consoleLogger2); 
        });
        function autoLoad() {
            $("form input").each(function() {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');  //WORKS!
                $(this).focus(); 
                           /*Should trigger the event-listener above 
                           to trigger consoleLogger1 above, but doesn't.*/
                $(this).blur();  
                           /*Should trigger the event-listener above 
                            to trigger consoleLogger2 above, but doesn't.*/
            });  
        }
    </script>

</head>

<!--MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM---DIVIDER---MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-->

<body onload="autoLoad()">
    <form>
        <input style="width: 136px;"></input><br>
        <input style="width: 136px;"></input><br>
        <input style="width: 136px;"></input><br>
        <input style="width: 136px;"></input><br>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it didn't work, but a successful workaround, was to remove the two event-listener lines...

```
       $("form input").on("focus", consoleLogger1); 
       $("form input").on("blur", consoleLogger2);
```

...from the `$(document).ready` function, and instead insert them as the first thing INSIDE the actual `autoLoader()` function.